# Remove specific object from Many-to-many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, many-to-many

I have Two models :

```
class Product(models.Model):
product_model = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='') 
...

class Discount(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True) 
    discount_percent = models.IntegerField(default=0,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(100),
            MinValueValidator(1),
        ]
    )
```

I want to delete specific item from items(ManyToManyField)

my views :

```
def delete_from_discount(request, id, product_url):
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        a = Product(product_url=product_url)
        b = Discount(id=id)
        b = b.items.remove(a)
        return redirect("/staff/discount/"+id)
    else:
        return redirect('/staff')
```

There is no error but also nothing change from my models, no remove
my html:

```
{% for dis in discount.items.all %}

<a href="/staff/discount/delete-from-discount/{{discount.id}}/{{dis.product_url}}/">delet</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your product needs a primary key. It is also not clear to me why you use `b = b.items...`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I used pk and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you aim to remove should have a primary key, or the field where the `ManyToManyField` is referring to, not a `Product` object without a primary key.

You thus should work with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def delete_from_discount(request, id, product_url):
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        a = get_object_or_404(Product, product_url=product_url)
        b = get_object_or_404(Discount, id=id)
        b.items.remove(a)
        return redirect("/staff/discount/"+id)
    else:
        return redirect('/staff')
```

You can prevent obtaining the Discount object from the database by working on the through model directly:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def delete_from_discount(request, id, product_url):
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        a = get_object_or_404(Product, product_url=product_url)
        Discount.items.through.objects.filter(discount_id=id, product=a)
        b.items.remove(a)
        return redirect("/staff/discount/"+id)
    else:
        return redirect('/staff')
```